# A different XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to JS world. I'm trying to make this short, but it's not working. Is this possible? If not why?

```
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(): xhr=new window.ActiveXObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your syntax is wrong. I would write it like this:

   ```
   var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject();
   ```
2. You need to pass a string to `ActiveXObject`. So:

   ```
   new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
   ```

   or

   ```
   new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   ```

   . You need them both for compatibility, by the way, so you won't be able to condense it into one line.

Comment: You have `window.XMLHttpRequest` and `XMLHttpRequest` in the same code which is not consistent. Use either one consistently. (I would use the shorter one.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That's a matter of personal preference. The `window.` is to check if it exists, if `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't exist and you omit the `window.` it will throw an error. Using `new window.XMLHttpRequest()` is a little ridiculous and pointless.

Comment: But that introduces the risk that the code will break if `XMLHttpRequest` has been shadowed by a local variable.

Comment: @Sime - I disagree.  Using `window.XMLHttpRequest` prevents a "undefined" error from being thrown. But once you know it exists, there is no reason to continue referencing `window`. **Edit:** commenting from my phone is way too slow. My comment is too late and now redundant.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I suppose. And anyone who does that either has a good reason to do so (providing missing functionality) or is just an idiot :)

Comment: @Sime - The alternative would be to use `typeof`, but that doesn't do anything to address the local variable shadowing issue. You would have to do more sophisticated type checking, but that seems a bit unnecessary in all but the most portable of distributed script libraries.

Comment: @gilly Yes, I don't think that's something we have to worry about. There are lots of names which could be shadowed (e.g. `setTimeout`, `parseInt`). I don't think that's something we have to guard against. My original concern was inconsistency, but as it turns out, there is a valid reason to prefix the name with `window.` at the LHS of the conditional operation.